# JSON error passing html

Tags: php, ajax, json, escaping

I have problem with JSON, passing html code, I don't understand because I  escaped with addslashes php function.

This is the JSON that fail:

With php JSON is valid:

```
<?php if(count($articles)): ?>
{"items":[
<?php foreach($articles as $key => $article): ?>
      <?php if($key==0  ):?>
      {
        "foto_g": "<?php echo $article->getRutafoto() ?>",
        "foto_th": "<?php echo $article->getRutathumb() ?>"

      }
    <?php else: ?>  
    ,
      {
        "foto_g": "<?php echo $article->getRutafoto() ?>",
        "foto_th": "<?php echo $article->getRutathumb() ?>"

      }
    <?php endif ?>  
<?php endforeach ?>
],
"nom_coleccio": "<?php echo $coleccio->getNom()?>"
,
"descripcio_coleccio": "<?php echo addslashes($coleccio->getDescripcio(ESC_RAW))?>"
}
<?php endif ?>
```

And the result that have problem is:

```
{
"descripcio_coleccio": "<p>El delta de l\'Ebre ha estat l\'escenari d\'inspiraci&oacute; d\'aquesta col&middot;lecci&oacute;.</p>
<p>La l&iacute;nia de l\'horitz&oacute; i el color del paisatge materialitzats en alumini s\'uneixen per a crear volum en forma de joia.</p>"
}
```

When is the problem?

Thanks Regards

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are reimplementing json_encode, badly?

Comment: It looks to me like you're embedding the call to encode your data, not the result of the call.

Comment: @mario YEs but my strcut is more big, i edited.

Comment: Maybe you should show what you're really doing.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you don't create an array structure with your quirky loops first, or at the very least use json_encode for the string values instead of manually enclosing it in `"` double quotes.

Comment: @mario Is possible, use json_encode with dinamic array?

Comment: Avoid to count the array in the if. You can just do `if ($articles)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use proper encoding functions if possible. In case of JSON you should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode), even if just for particular values.

But it would be easier if you collect the values in an array with associative keys and use `json_encode` only at the end:

```
if (count($articles)) {
    $items = array();
    foreach ($articles as $key => $article) {
        $items[] = array(
            "foto_g"  => $article->getRutafoto(),
            "foto_th" => $article->getRutathumb()
        }
    }
    $data = array(
        "items"               => $items,
        "nom_coleccio"        => $coleccio->getNom(),
        "descripcio_coleccio" => $coleccio->getDescripcio(ESC_RAW)
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that! Construct the JSON properly in PHP instead:

```
<?php
        echo json_encode(array
        (
            "descripcio_coleccio" => $coleccio->getDescripcio(ESC_RAW)
        ));
?>
```

Comment: Yes but my JSON is more big. I eidted post with all JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Those single quotes shouldn't be escaped:

```
{
    "descripcio_coleccio": "<p>Eldeltadel'Ebrehaestatl'escenarid'inspiraci&oacute;d'aquestacol&middot;lecci&oacute;.</p><p>Lal&iacute;niadel'horitz&oacute;ielcolordelpaisatgematerialitzatsenaluminis'uneixenperacrearvolumenformadejoia.</p>"
}
```